# How to assign role to admin user Programmatically in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I need to assign a user role to admin user programmatically in Magento. How can I? I tried some methods like,

```
try {
$user->setRoleIds(array(<role_id>))
->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
->saveRelations();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
exit;
}
```

But when we apply the above code, the database get corrupted and gets an Error - `"Parent Role id 'G5' does not exist"`.

This is because, when I apply the above code, the admin user with parent role Id is get deleted and I cant access the backend there after, even If I recreate it again!

Can anyone point out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Strange! But finaly got a solution from [here](http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-create-an-admin-account-from-magento-code/).

Gave a try catch like this,

```
         try {
          $role = Mage::getModel("admin/role");
          $role->setParent_id(5);
          $role->setTree_level(1);
          $role->setRole_type('U');
          $role->setUser_id($user_id);
          $role->save();
          echo "Your username: ".$username.", and password: ".$password;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

and it Worked. Here `parent Id` is my custom role id. `$user_id` is the id of user to whome role should be attached.